# Error in Calling an array element inside a if condition?

Tags: ios, xcode

When i call this if condition, The condition inside the if does not get executed. 
Code used to call an element

```
if([NSNumber numberWithFloat:(([[[shared instance].y objectAtIndex:0] floatValue]))>10])
{
 [MONObject sharedInstance1[.counterPlus++;  //counter used to update the value
}
```

Counter value gets updated irrespective of the condition inside if? Is this the way to get a element from the array and compare?

Note: i have created a single tone array!
Please help me!

Comment: Start by unpacking the expression inside `if (...)` into 3 or 4 statements so that you can see what the different values are and what is being referenced/compared.

Comment: How to do it? No idea, I m new to xcode and ios! A deep insight to my problem-> Thank you for the reply! No. [[shared instance].y objectAtIndex:0] array contains 6 elements where this array's 1st element get updated every time it goes through a loop. so I want to compare whether it's greater than 10 and update my counter! I think problem is the way i tired to access the array inside the if condition! Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Don't try and cram everything into one statement** - this is terrible coding style, hard to debug (as you've found) and awful to maintain. Use some intermediate variables so you can see what's going on.

The reason the condition is always true, is that your if statement boils down to:

```
if ([NSNumber numberWithFloat: <something>])...
```

`-[NSNumber numberWithFloat:]` is always true - in fact any object always equates to true. So even `[NSNumber numberWithBool: NO]` is true.

If you just want to check whether your value is greater than 10 (assuming your array contains `NSNumber`s), you need:

```
NSNumber * someNumber = [[shared instance].y objectAtIndex:0];

if([someNumber floatValue] > 10)
{
    [MONObject sharedInstance1[.counterPlus++;  //counter used to update the value
}
```

Comment: Dear sir, I m new to xcode. Any method to read the first value inside the array and check whether it's greater than 10? In the next section I have to compare something more complex than this, Even more than 2 or 3 elements inside the if condition of the same array? Please suggest me a way? Thank you!

Comment: See my updated answer - I'm sure you can figure the rest out for yourself.

Comment: Dear Ashley, It works! Seems to go well, But i need to implement other logics inside if loop and see how it goes. Is this method good? I m new to this programming and my code need to have low computational time. SO is this method good is manipulating a dynamic array which changes within a for loop and uses it's value to compute certain outputs and compare it's value using if condition? Thank you for ur help! U made my hard working day fruitful!

Answer (score 1):

Once I decode all your brackets, it appears that you are testing whether or not a NSNumber object was being created.

Comment: Dear sir, I m new to xcode. Any method to read the first value inside the array and check whether it's greater than 10? Thank you!

Comment: What is the class of the object in the array?  How was its value set in the first place?

Comment: This array is implemented as a singleton, where it updates it's value from the accelerometer of the ipod.Since it has 6 elements, during every update it removes it's 6th element and then insert it to the 1st position, But the problem is i can arithmetically compute a output value using the above expressions i used. But unable to compare the values in it! Totally lost! please help me!

Comment: I repeat, "What is the class of the object in the array?"

Comment: @sam being new to Xcode is not an excuse for not reading the docs. Anyways, this is not in any way related to Xcode. You can do Objective-C programming with a minimalist Objective-C compiler + text editor. Please, please, use correct terminology.

Answer (score 1):

If that is your actual code, you have a backwards bracket...

```
[MONObject sharedInstance1[.counterPlus++;
```

should be

```
[MONObject sharedInstance1].counterPlus++;
```

Comment: No no, it's just mistake in typing! :) Sorry for that! I have commented on the problem above! If you can please help me!